# Getting error "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: 16: exec: redis-server --port 6000: not found" inside docker container

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

I'm starting up a docker container using docker compose and passing the port I want it to use. But the command to start redis is not working and is saying it's not found:

> /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: 16: exec: redis-server --port 6000: not found

**docker-compose**

```
version: '2.1'
services:

  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - ${Ports_Exposed_Redis}:${Ports_Exposed_Redis}
    command: 
      - redis-server --port ${Ports_Exposed_Redis}
```

I pass `Ports_Exposed_Redis` as an environment variable like:

`export Ports_Exposed_Redis=6000`

How do i pass it the port to run redis on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `- redis-server --port ${Ports_Exposed_Redis}`, this means you want to use `exec form` of `CMD`, but your yaml format is wrong, refers to [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command):

You should use:

```
command:
    - redis-server
    - --port
    - ${Ports_Exposed_Redis}
```

Or:

```
command: ["redis-server", "--port", "${Ports_Exposed_Redis}"]
```

Comment: @atlinr Thank you. If I do that, can I also run another command? Because it looks like it's all one line being constructed

Comment: No, just last command will effect. You may want to have a look for https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/, and here command just act as the parameters of docker-entrypoint.sh, and finally will be executed by `exec` to replace the current process, see [this](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/master/5.0/docker-entrypoint.sh)